# How can I do an overlapping sequence count in Biopython?

Tags: python

Biopython's `.count()` methods, like Python's `str.count()`, perform a non-overlapping count, how can I do an overlapping one?

For example, these code snippets `return 2`, but I want the answer `3`:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> Seq('AAAA').count('AA')
2
>>> 'AAAA'.count('AA')
2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Biopython 1.70, there is a new `Seq.count_overlap()` method, which includes optional `start` and `end` arguments:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> Seq('AAAA').count_overlap('AA')
3
>>> Seq('AAAA').count_overlap('AA', 1, 4)
2
```

This method is also implemented for the `MutableSeq` and `UnknownSeq` classes:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import MutableSeq, UnknownSeq
>>> MutableSeq('AAAA').count_overlap('AA')
3
>>> UnknownSeq(4, character='A').count_overlap('AA')
3
```

---

Disclaimer: I co-contributed the `.count_overlap()` methods with Peter Cock, see [`97709cc`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/97709cc7a4b8591e794b442796d41e4f7b855a0f)

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered this problem before, and used python `re` module to solve this problem.

```
import re
all = re.findall(r'(?=(AA))','AAAA')
counts = len(all)
```

You can get more details in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

Comment: This is a valid approach, and you could add start and end arguments easily enough, but it's not very memory efficient for large sequences. `re.finditer` would be better for that. Also, `UnknownSeq` type objects require a rather different approach to maximize memory efficiency

Answer (score 4):

You can use `finditer` from python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) module. The advantage of this approach is it allows for getting the indices of those matches, which could be handy down the track.

```
>>> import re
>>> matches = re.finditer(r'(?=(AA))', 'AAAA')
>>> indices = [match.span(1) for match in matches]
>>> indices
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
>>> num_matches = len(indices)
>>> num_matches
3
```